# Índice devuelve el primero que ingreso listas enlzadas, ordenamiento

Tags: c++, indices

tengo un problema con el índice, al mostrar los usuarios ingresados, me muestra en su índice el numero del primero que ingrese, y no el de cada uno. pero al momento de ordénalo este si muestra el índice de cada uno y no los dos iguales. No me muestra el error
Sinceramente no se que hacer, busco ayuda y asesoramiento de como corregir este error y futuros errores que me puedan pasar por lo mismo.

¿Qué puedo hacer? ¿Es por que uso listas con un array? ¿o mi problema viene desde mi nodo? adjunto el código que estoy elaborando. uso las librerías iostream,stdlib.h y conio.h
adjunto imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
struct nodo{
    int nuc;
    string nom,ape;
    nodo *siguiente;
};
void intercambiar(int *a, int *b) {
  int temporal = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temporal;
}
void insertar(nodo *&lista,int nu,string no,string ap)
{
    nodo *nvo_nodo = new nodo(); 
    nvo_nodo -> nuc=nu;   
    nvo_nodo -> nom=no;
    nvo_nodo -> ape=ap;
    nodo *aux1 = lista;  
    nodo *aux2;         
while ( aux1 != NULL ) {
    aux2 = aux1;               
    aux1 = aux1 -> siguiente;    
        }
if (lista == aux1) {       
lista = nvo_nodo;           
}
else {
aux2 -> siguiente = nvo_nodo;
}
nvo_nodo -> siguiente = aux1;
cout<<"\t Cliente " <<nu<< " insertado a la lista correctamente" <<endl;
}
void mostrar(nodo *lista)
{
    nodo *actual= new nodo(); 
    actual = lista;
    while(actual !=NULL){
        cout<<actual->nuc<<endl;
        cout<<actual->nom<<endl;
        cout<<actual->ape<<endl;
        actual = actual -> siguiente;
        cout<<"_________________________________________"<<endl;
    }
}
void seleccion(int nuc[],int longitud)
{
    int i,j,x;
    for(i=0;i<longitud-1;i++)
    {
    for(j=i+1;j<longitud;j++)
    {
        if(nuc[i>nuc[j]])
        {
            intercambiar(&nuc[i],&nuc[j]);
        }
        cout<<"    "<<nuc[i]<<"  "<<nuc[j];
        }
        cout<<"Clientes "<<endl;
    for(x=0;x<longitud;x++) 
    {
        cout<<"    "<<nuc[x];
    }
}
}
main()
{
    nodo *lista = NULL;
    int nuc,*valores,can,i,num;
    valores=new int[can];
    int longitud=sizeof(valores)/sizeof(*valores);
    string nom,ape,sn;
            cout<<"¿Cuantos clientes ingresara a la plataforma?"<<endl;
            cin>>can;
            system("cls");
            for(i=0;i<can;i++)
            {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Clientes ingresados: "<<i<<endl;
            cout<<"numero de cuenta"<<endl;
            cin>>nuc;
            cout<<"nombre del cliente"<<endl;
            cin>>nom;
            cout<<"apellido del cliente"<<endl;
            cin>>ape;
            valores[i]=nuc+1;
            insertar(lista,*valores,nom,ape);
            }
            cout<<"Lista"<<endl;
            mostrar(lista);
            cout<<"Metodo SELECCION"<<endl;
            seleccion(valores,longitud);    
}
```

Comment: De antemano gracias por tomarse el tiempo de enseñarme o mostrarme mi error

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

Tu programa tiene unos cuantos errores. Veamos:

**Usas variables sin inicializar**

```
int can;
valores=new int[can];
```

Si tu intención es que la capacidad de `valores` se adapte al valor de `can`... no lo estás haciendo bien. La instrucción `new` se ejecuta en el mismo momento en el que la invocas, y ahí coge el valor de `can` (variable no inicializada) y usará ese valor para calcular la capacidad de la reserva de memoria. Una vez hecha la reserva, la misma será autónoma y no va a cambiar por mucho que modifiques `can`.

El puntero `valores` debes inicializarlo **después** de conocer el valor de `can`:

```
cout<<"¿Cuantos clientes ingresara a la plataforma?"<<endl;
cin>>can;
int * valores = new int[can];
```

**Separar responsabilidades**

Una cosa es una lista y otra los nodos de la lista. Por tu propia salud, no deberías exponer la lógica de la lista a todo el programa. Entiendo que estás empezando a programar en C++ y aun no has visto lo que sería la creación de objetos, pero eso no es impedimento para intentar hacer las cosas bien.

La estructura `nodo` puedes dejarla como está:

```
struct nodo{
    int nuc;
    string nom,ape;
    nodo *siguiente = nullptr;
};
```

Sin embargo, todo quedaría más bonito y legible si creases una estructura para gestionar la lista:

```
struct lista {
    nodo * root = nullptr;
};
```

Parece un cambio absurdo, pero cuando empieces a programar objetos, este diseño te permitirá aislar completamente el diseño de la lista. Además, al poseer C++ un tipado fuerte, te permitirá distinguir las funciones que manipulan la lista de las funciones que manipulan nodos ... no podrás mezclar las funciones por error puesto que el tipo `nodo` no puede ser usado como si fuese el tipo `lista` y viceversa.

A modo de ejemplo, la función `insertar` quedaría ahora así:

```
void insertar(lista & lista, int nu, string no, string ap)
{
    nodo * nvo_nodo = new nodo; 
    nvo_nodo -> nuc=nu;   
    nvo_nodo -> nom=no;
    nvo_nodo -> ape=ap;

    if (lista.root == nullptr)
    {
        lista.root = nvo_nodo;
    }
    else
    {
        nodo * aux = lista.root;
        while (aux->siguiente != nullptr)
        {
            aux = aux->siguiente;
        }
        aux->siguiente = nvo_nodo;
    }
    cout << "\t Cliente " << nu << " insertado a la lista correctamente\n";
}
```

**Cálculos incorrectos**

```
int longitud=sizeof(valores)/sizeof(*valores);
```

Este mecanismo te permite calcular el tamaño de un **array**. El problema es que `valores` no es un array sino **un puntero**.

`sizeof` es una función que se evalúa en tiempo de compilación, es decir, mientras se está creando el código binario. En ese momento el compilador no puede saber qué valor va a introducir el usuario (tiempo de ejecución).

Lo que sí se conoce en tiempo de compilación es el número de bytes que ocupa un puntero. Así, en arquitecturas de 64 bits, los punteros ocupan típicamente 8 bytes. Pues bien, dado que `sizeof(*valores)` devuelve el tamaño de un `int`, `longitud` acabará valiendo `2`:

```
int longitud = 8 / 4 = 2;
```

Y esto será así siempre, independientemente del número que introduzcas al ejecutar el programa.

Esto es un problema, ya que utilizas este valor para ordenar los resultados.

Si te fijas, verás que ya tienes el número de elementos, ese valor se encuentra en la variable `can`:

```
int longitud = can;
```

**Nombres de variables**

No debes racanear a la hora de darle nombre a las variables. Tienes que dar a las variables y a las funciones nombres concisos que indiquen claramente cual es su responsabilidad.

Si no sigues esta regla, acabarás escribiendo código ofuscado, dificil de leer y de seguir. Mientras recuerdes exactamente cómo está estructurado tu programa no será un problema, pero después será algo que te va a dar dolores de cabeza.

Nombres como `can`, `nuc`, `nom` no son nada recomendables. En el código binario resultante no hay nombres de variables, por lo que da igual cuan largo sea el nombre que le des a una variable ... no va a tener ningún impacto en la forma en la que se ejecute tu programa y, sin embargo, si que puede facilitarte o complicarte la vida a la hora de modificar tu código.

**Acceso incorrecto a índices**

```
if(nuc[i>nuc[j]])
```

Este condicional no es correcto y el motivo es que has metido una comparación en el cálculo del índice. Un código equivalente sería el siguiente:

```
int index = i>nuc[j] ? 1 : 0
bool value = nuc[index] != 0;
if (value)
```

Lo que pretendías hacer yo creo que se parece más a esto:

```
if(nuc[i]>nuc[j])
```

**No liberas la memoria dinámica**

Como norma general, por cada llamada que hagas a `new`, debe haber otra llamada a `delete` en tu código. En tu caso esta simetría no se cumple. No liberas absolutamente ninguno de los nodos de la lista.

En tu código no pasa nada porque tu programa es muy sencillo y esa memoria se liberará automáticamente al finalizar el programa, pero si modificas tu programa para que, por ejemplo, se puedan sacar elementos de la lista, entonces ya si puedes empezar a tener un problema. La memoria asociada a los nodos que saques de la lista no se liberará y por ello la memoria que necesita tu programa para funcionar se irá incrementando paulatinamente. Con el número adecuado de iteraciones, tu programa podría llegar a consumir toda la memoria del equipo.

Aunque parezca algo innecesario, libera la memoria de la lista antes de finalizar el programa. Es mejor acostumbrarse a hacerlo siempre a arriesgarse a que tu algoritmo tenga lagunas de memoria.

**Tu programa pierde memoria**

```
void mostrar(nodo *lista)
{
    nodo *actual= new nodo(); 
    actual = lista;
```

Estás inicializando el puntero `actual` para que direccione a un objeto de tipo `nodo` que acabas de crear para, a continuación, modificar ese puntero, haciendo que apunte a `lista`. La memoria reservada en la primera línea se ha perdido y ya no serás capaz de liberarla (no sabes su dirección de memoria)

Aquí vemos un caso en el que separar los conceptos de pila y lista puede ayudarte a programar mejor.

Para empezar, no se espera que esta función modifique la lista, luego se le puede pasar el parámetro como constante para asegurarnos:

```
void mostrar(lista const& lista)
{
    nodo * aux = lista.root;
    while(aux !=NULL){
        cout << aux->nuc << '\n'
             << aux->nom << '\n'
             << aux->ape << '\n';
        aux = aux->siguiente;
        cout<<"_________________________________________\n";
    }
}
```

Si te fijas, tiendo a eliminar los usos de `std::endl`. Esto lo suelo hacer porque `endl` fuerza a que se vacie el buffer de `cout`. Esta operación es bastante lenta, por lo que usar `endl` alegremente puede llegar a impactar negativamente en los tiempos de ejecución de tu programa.